# Exporting string to MAT file

Tags: export

I'm trying to export a string to a Matlab mat file. Is it possible? The straightforward way

```
Export["file.mat", {{"1"}}, {{"Data"}}]
```

with any number of surrounding braces does not work for me, as I get the error message

```
Export::type: ({"1"}) cannot be exported to the ("MAT")format.
```

Any clues?

**Edit**

To make this a little clearer: I'd like to save some matrices **and** a string to the same MAT file.

Comment: Could you perhaps describe the MAT format for those of us unfamiliar with it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately I can't. It's a binary fileformat used by Matlab. The Mathematica doc says that the "Data" element can store "numerical or textual data given as a multidimensional array". But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid *Mathematica* may not support this natively.  In [the documentation for `.MAT`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MAT.html):

> Export["file.mat",expr] exports any numeric array to a MAT-file.
>
> Export["file.mat",expr] creates a MAT-file from an array of integers or doubles.

While the documentation claims that:

> Import fully supports MAT Level 4 and 5 files.

It makes no such claim for `Export`, stately only:

> Export generates MAT 4 files.

---

For reference the binary MAT format is described in [this PDF file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf).  It says that level 4 MAT files may contain one or more matrices, but each one may only contain a single data type.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up! It didn't think of looking up the MAT specification for the different versions, I just saw that it is possible to store strings with my version of Matlab.