# How do I export matrices into matlab format?

Tags: export

For example:

```
M={}; 
For[n = 0, n < 100, n = n + 1,
  ... ...   
 M=Append[M, Resultmatrix ]; 
 (*Resultmatrix is the intermediate reslut 4X4 matrix*)
]
Export["data.mat", M]
```

But when loading data.mat in Matlab, I find that M splits into multiple variables with names like Expression1, Expression2, Expression3 ....
I also tried XLS format, but each 4x4 matrix in the list of matrices appears in an individual worksheet.
    So my question is how can I put M in a single variable, thus I could manipulate it.

Comment: You can create the list in one go: `m = Array[#1 - 1 &, {100, 4, 4}]`

Comment: You could export `Flatten[m]` and then use reshape(Expression,[100 4 4]) (not sure about syntax) in the other software.

Comment: thanks ssch and b.gatessucks ,M is not a constant matrix, posted is just an example, Flatten[m] does work, but I found reshape changed the structure of M.

Comment: @user5463 The structure is different because one uses row major ordering and the other column major ordering to store the arrays. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/5) and the answers there for a way to convert (the answers deal with converting in mma... you can do something similar in matlab)

Comment: also relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6837/exporting-a-large-multidimensional-sparse-array

Comment: rm -rf♦ thanks，first I Flatten[m] in Mma， then reshape(m,4,4,100) in Matlab. Due to the ordering difference, one has to transpose each 4X4 matrtix to regain the original matrix.

Answer (score 11):

[See the link for import and export examples for mat files](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MAT.html) also [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8904/exporting-string-to-mat-file?rq=1)

Below examples work:

```
Export["file.mat", {"Var1" -> {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}, "Var2" -> {{4, 5, 6}}}, "LabeledData"]
```

So, use labels and Labeled data options.

Comment: What do the brackets do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the hdf5 format instead if you have too many dimensions. Saves a lot of pain and both Matlab and Mathematica support the hdf5 format.